# Downloading files using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, curl, download

I used this function for downloading SWF files(flash games) sucessfully. When I use this script for one particular site it downloads all games(I told the script to download 4 games from a list) with exact size of 299bytes? I tried downloading these games with Google Chrome and the download is sucessfull. Is there something missing in the CURL functions I use or the download algorithm is not good enough? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function saveFlash($fullPaths,$folder,$gamenames,$i){
        $curl = curl_init($fullPaths[$i]);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //Create a new file in the given folder
        $fp = fopen($folder."/".$gamenames[$i].".swf", 'w');
            if ($fp == FALSE){ 
                echo "File not opened<br>";} 
        //Ask cURL to write the contents to a file
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        //Execute the cURL session
        curl_exec ($curl);
        //Close cURL session and file
        curl_close ($curl);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Text editor gives the following

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.freeonlinegames.com/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at freeonlinegames.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at those 299 byte files with a text editor? Most likely it'll be "Sorry, no direct access allowed" error messages of some sort.

Comment: Your script gets blocked. Look into the returned data (should be HTML) for a reason.

Comment: It says the document has moved

Comment: <title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.freeonlinegames.com/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at freeonlinegames.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to allow it to follow the redirects.

You may also want to set a `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` so it doesn't redirect out of control.

Answer (score 1):

That error you're getting is a common way of telling you that no hotlinking is allowed.  If you simply want to download the SWF, you need to set the referrer.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://urlofpagetheswfwasfoundon');
```

If it still doesn't work after that, you might need to set an appropriate user-agent string.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 Something Something');
```

Also, be very sure that you are allowed to do what you are trying to do.  Ripping stuff off others' sites is very frowned upon, and usually illegal.

Comment: Really want to test this lines of code because of the knowledge but is it possible for this site to track my IP and fill lawsuit against me? As a starting web developer I should know how do defend my site from CURL attacks.

Comment: Absolutely, and if you think for one minute that we are going to help you break the law, then you are on the wrong site, and are not welcome here.  I have provided this example to help you learn, not to help you be an ass.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to be an ass. Knowing more about using CURL and defending from CURL isn't something wrong. Should test this code on my server from friend's PC.

Comment: Correct.  Nothing wrong with learning, which is what this information is for.  You suggested that you were nervous about being tracked.  If you have permission, then there is no problem.